# wso2 APIManager: Add PingIdentity as new OAuth-Endpoint

Tags: oauth-2.0, wso2, wso2-api-manager, pingfederate

We are planing to use PingFederate-Server as our central identity managment solution. What are the steps to integrate the ping server oauth-endpoint to our wso2 landscape.
Is there already a solution available?

I read the blog-post https://amilasnotes.wordpress.com/2015/05/19/integrating-with-a-third-party-oauth-provider-overview and it looks like that this task is possible.

Has someone experienced replacing the internal wso2 key-manager?

And is it possible to use both keymanagement solution (interal and ping), so that we don't need to migrate the current applications/access-tokens?

Thx, in advance
Marty

Answer (score 1):

You have to write a custom keymanager implementation to connect to Ping identity server. Overall implementation steps can be found in https://amilasnotes.wordpress.com/2015/05/19/integrating-with-a-third-party-oauth-provider-overview/

There are two sample keymanager implementations you can look into. [Surf Oauth](https://amilasnotes.wordpress.com/2015/05/10/using-surf-oauth-authorization-server-as-a-key-manager/) and [Mitre-ID Connect](https://amilasnotes.wordpress.com/2015/12/29/integrating-api-manager-with-mitre-id-connect/).

You can checkout the API manager default keymanager implementation as well. See [AMDefaultKeyManagerImpl](https://github.com/wso2/carbon-apimgt/blob/v5.0.3/components/apimgt/org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/apimgt/impl/AMDefaultKeyManagerImpl.java) .

Regarding using both key managers, It won't be possible since default KM implementation is also written using the same keymanager interface. So only one keymanager implementation can be used.